# Same Docker image forwards X11 one host but not on another

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, dockerfile, x11-forwarding

I have created a simple Docker image which contains **SSH + xeyes**. I run that container, connect to the container via SSH using X11 Forwarding and want to be able to display **xeyes**.

I have built and run the Docker container on host A. When I connect to the container, **it does not work** `Error: Can't open display:`

I have build and run the Docker container on another host, B. **And it works like a charm.**

I don't understand the difference...

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENV SSH_PASSWORD "rootpass"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -qqy x11-apps openssh-server ssh

# Install SSH access
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo "root:$SSH_PASSWORD" | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

CMD [ "/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D" ]
EXPOSE 22
```

On host A and B, I do:

- Build the image with `docker build -t myeyes .`
- Run the container with : `docker run -d -p 7222:22 --name myeyes myeyes`.

Then, from another host C, I do `xhost +` and I try those containers:

It **fails** for the container on A:

```
$ ssh -X -p 7222 root@IP-of-A
...
# env | grep DISPLAY
# xeyes 
Error: Can't open display: 
# grep X11Forward /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
X11Forwarding yes
# ls -al 
-rw-------  1 root root  180 Sep 29 09:32 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Oct 22  2015 .bashrc
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Sep 29 09:04 .cache
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  148 Aug 17  2015 .profile
```

It **works** for the container on B:

```
$ ssh -X -p 7222 root@IP-of-B
...
# env | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
# grep X11Forward /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
X11Forwarding yes
# ls -al
-rw-------  1 root root   58 Sep 29 09:34 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 root root   59 Sep 29 09:33 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Oct 22  2015 .bashrc
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Sep 29 09:21 .cache
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  148 Aug 17  2015 .profile
# cat .Xauthority
...
MAGIC COOKIE
...
# xeyes
```

Note that on B, I have a valid **.Xauthority** and **DISPLAY**. However, I didn't do anything particular to set them up, so **why aren't they being set on the container for A?**

Finally host A is a Linux Mint 18.1 laptop. Host B is a Debian Jessie.

Comment: Do you have GUI on Host A or you are running all of it in command line mode?

Comment: I have GUI on both host A and host B.

Comment: Do you have a package named xauth on host A? If not try installing it.

Comment: Yes I tried to add xauth in the Dockerfile. But it's still the same problem.

Comment: The only difference that I see is that :

on host A: Docker version 17.06.1-ce

on host B: Docker version 1.12.3

Comment: Run `find / -name ".Xauthority"` and see if you can find the file on Host A? Also see if this helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/21923/how-do-i-create-the-xauthority-file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155644/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user1381).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling verbose info in ssh, I noticed the following messages:

```
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
...
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

I then searched the web for ["X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"](https://sites.google.com/site/xiangyangsite/home/technical-tips/linux-unix/common-tips/how-to-fix-x11-forwarding-request-failed-on-channel-0) and **found the solution**: in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, add:

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

And **then ssh -X works correctly everywhere**.

So, this command must be added to the Dockerfile for my containers:

```
RUN echo "X11UseLocalhost no" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```